# JQuery and SVG - how to find the 'g' tag

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-svg

Imagine this:

```
<svg>
    <g id="node1" class="node"></g>
    <g id="node2" class="node"></g>
</svg>
```

How can I find the 'g' tag, I want that all tags could be clicked, and not just 'node1' or 'node2'. I've tried simular to this, but could not get it work.

```
$('g').click(function(){
    alert("Hellooooo");
});
```

Comment: Unable to replicate. `$('g').click()` works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/ZLnJw/

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. I've tried it again and it works for me to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use find() method for more info visit [this](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

For eg `$("body").find("p").css("background-color","#f00");` sets all body's `<p>` element background-color to red.

For your question try this:

```
$("svg").find("g").click(function(){

// your jquery code here

}
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate it.

Comment: This... is a silly answer. `$('svg').find('g')` is exactly the same as `$('g')` but with an extra unnecessary method call. Equally you can just use `$('p').css({...});`. No need for `find()` here at all.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly what happen if inside other tags is also "g" then he need to find within "svg" only.

Comment: @C-Link `g` is only a valid SVG tag. Unless developing a shadow DOM site (which is unlikely in its current state), `g` will always be the child of `svg`.

Comment: Oh! I don't know svg so I'd provided that answer. Anyway thanx.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly also in his question he tried but not worked saying, why? I think here is find() method is right to choose.

Comment: For flat <svg> docs, use `$('g')`, but when dealing with nested <svg> inside <svg>, I'd use `$('svg')[0].find('g')` to navigate the DOM tree.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to C-Link I've solved this.

To be sure only the nodes are clickable I've wroted:

```
$("svg").find("g.node").click(function(){
    alert("Lolol");
});
```

And it works fine.

Comment: +1. Don't deserve a downvote as it is good to know the long way and short way. As explained above, in some cases, you'd need the long method.