# How can I retrieve an image element's code using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If you have an image element, say an SVG. How do you retrieve the image code, in such a way that the output could look like the following

```
<svg ...></svg>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The same as you would for any other element? `$("svg")`?

Comment: Also - Possible duplicate of [JQuery and SVG - how to find the 'g' tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043318/jquery-and-svg-how-to-find-the-g-tag)

Comment: Is that exactly what you're looking for? [Conversion of JPEG to SVG in Javascript - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022774/conversion-of-jpeg-to-svg-in-javascript#41182213)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an `img` tag that looks like this

```html
<img src="whatever.svg">
```

you could find the value of `src` and perform a fetch to that URL to get the underlying XML:

```
async function getSVGXML(selector) {
  const url = $(selector).attr('src');
  return await fetch(url).then(res => res.text());
}
```